# Dynamic Column Index Name Error in Formula

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, dynamic-columns

I am trying to calculate the component q'ty from Sheet Plan to Sheet Result by using Vlookup to fill in column,having:

- `Count_col`: is the total column in sheet `Plan`
- `Last_col`: is the total column in sheet `Result` (before add column Demand)

Sheet Results

| Material | Component | Demand W1 | Demand W2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD1000 | nc200 | #NAME? | #NAME? |

Sheet Plan

| Material | Demand W1 | Demand W2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD1000 | 1000 | 200 |

```
    For i = 1 To count_col
        Cells(1, i + last_col).Value = "=Plan!RC[-2]"
        Cells(1, i + last_col).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,Plan!C1:C15,i+1,0)"
    Next i
```

But the result is name error, I checked the spelling of function is correct and dont know how to fix. Why there is "@" in my formula?

Detail of error

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Plan!$A:$O,@i+1,0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i+1` inside `""` behaves like a string rather than a variable. Try this.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,Plan!C1:C15," & i + 1 & ",0)"
```

Also avoid the use of `.Select`. Your code can be written as

```
Cells(1, i + last_col).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(RC1,Plan!C1:C15," & i + 1 & ",0)"
```

Recommended Reading: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Also you are mixing `R1C1` and `A1` style of referencing. I would recommend using one of them. A simple Google search `R1C1 vs A1 style` will explain what they are.

In `R1C1`, `Plan!C1:C15` needs to be written as `Plan!R1C3:R15C3`. So your final code would be

```
Cells(1, i + last_col).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(RC1,Plan!R1C3:R15C3," & i + 1 & ",0)"
```